# Copying Row Except Last Column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an `Excel VBA` macro and one of the tasks is to copy a subset of the data from a sheet to another.

I currently use the below, which copies the whole row fine (C is a row index):

```
Dim ConsolidatedRow As Excel.Range
Set ConsolidatedRow = ConsolidatedSheet.Range("A" & C).EntireRow
...
ConsolidatedRow.Copy Destination:=ResultSheet.Range("A" & ResultRowIndex)
```

I want to copy `ConsolidatedRow`, but without the last column. This last column is used in other operations between declaration and copy so the ideal solution would be a change to the copy statement. I've tried offsets, updating the range in `ConsolidatedRow` and loads of other things but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried resize?

Comment: ColsolidatedRow.Resize(ColsolidatedRow.Rows.Count,ColsolidatedRow.Columns.Count - 1)

Comment: Resize didn't work sadly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use the Range.End property to locate the last used cell.  Helps out if your row doesn't extend out as far as others in your sheet.  Replace the Set ConsolidatedRow command with the following:

```
With ConsolidatedSheet
    CopyExtent = .Range("A" & C).End(xlToRight).Column - 1
    Set ConsolidatedRow = .Range(.Cells(C, 1), .Cells(C, CopyExtent))
End With
```

This assumes you have no gaps in your data.  If you have blank cells that you want included in the copied section, change to this:

```
CopyExtent = ConsolidatedSheet.Cells(C, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't use columns behind this consolidatedRow in this worksheet, add two lines after set

```
Set ConsolidatedRow = Intersect(ConsolidatedSheet.UsedRange, ConsolidatedRow)
Set ConsolidatedRow = ConsolidatedRow.Resize(1, ConsolidatedRow.Columns.Count - 1)
```

Comment: I do use columns and sadly this didn't work but thanks.